# Using (Select * from a table ) to insert data into a table

Tags: python, mysql

I have bottom MySql query (sql1).

```
sq1 = 'select course_id, creator_id, max(course_num) + 1, recordid 
  ' from Courses where recordid in' \
  ' (' + ','.join(map(str, RecordMatch1)) + ') group by recordid'
cursor.execute(sql1)
```

BTW, RecordMatch1 is an object that has matching data from other previous queries.

I am trying to see if this is possible;  (**select * from sql1**) portion.

```
sql2 = ' insert into Courses (course_id, creator_id, course_num, record_id) '\
   ' Values ( select * from sql1)'
cursor.execute(sql2)
```

Or do I have to express everything rather than using (Select * )?

What is best practice?

Comment: You don't write `INSERT INTO table1 (col, col, ...) SELECT (col, col, ...) FROM table2` without the word "values".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you should specify columns in case of schema changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to confirm you are trying to run a select query and insert its output to a insert query. If that is the case this appears to be good.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can but you should do something like

```
sql = "SELECT course_id, creator_id, course_num, record_id FROM Courses" 
all = cursor.fetchall()
for i in range(len(all))
    sql1 = "INSERT INTO Courses (course_id, creator_id, course_num, record_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql1, (all[i]['Key'], all[i]['Key2'], all[i]['Key3'], all[i]['Key3']))
```

you can change the select like you want, remember that return a dictionary so take care about the keys, add `print(all)` to see what happen with the select and see the keys of each column

Comment: How do I modify areas such as 'Key', 'Key2', 'Key3' listed on the top?

Comment: comment all the for statement and type print(all[0]) before the for function and tell me

Comment: that should return a dictionary, so you have to refer the key of the value in all[i]['key']

Comment: I posted a separate question on here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45945750/insert-into-table-using-for-in-range-and-keys-of-the-value)